# React with Tailwind with HeadlessUI - how to add plugin configuration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, headless-ui, shopify-hydrogen

I've a react app using Tailwind with some Headless UI tabs.
I'm trying to style the tabs when active but in order to do that I had to include a new package.  Namely @headlessui/tailwindcss found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@headlessui/tailwindcss).

This is the example they document...

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@headlessui/tailwindcss')

    // Or with a custom prefix:
    require('@headlessui/tailwindcss')({ prefix: 'ui' })
  ],
}
```

However, I don't use requires in my project (modules, ES2022)... I use imports.  This is what my plugins section looks like at the moment...

```
import formsPlugin from "@tailwindcss/forms";
import typographyPlugin from "@tailwindcss/typography";
```

// ...then inside the config...

```
plugins: [formsPlugin, typographyPlugin]
```

How do I add "@headlessui/tailwindcss" into the plugins using an import approach?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring assignment and importing the plugin directly.

```
import formsPlugin from "@tailwindcss/forms";
import typographyPlugin from "@tailwindcss/typography";
import headlessUITailwindCSSPlugin from "@headlessui/tailwindcss";

// ...then inside the config...

plugins: [formsPlugin, typographyPlugin, headlessUITailwindCSSPlugin()]
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  I bow to your superior intelligence!